# Python renaming only the first of many nodes in xml

Tags: xml, python-3.x

im working on a python solution that gets an xml file from a REST api. while i have no trouble mapping the regular fields from the software, their custom fields need a little work however.

the issue that has me stumped at the moment is that the xml file looks like this.

```
    <Label>zip</Label>
    <Value>6230</Value>
    <Label>city</Label>
    <Value>Rødekro</Value>
    <Label>country</Label>
    <Value>Danmark</Value>
    <Label>date</Label>
    <Value>09/20/2018</Value>
```

and what i need is the following.

```
    <zip>6230</zip>
    <city>Rødekro</city>
    <country>Danmark</country>
    <date>09/20/2018</date>
```

is there a way where i can select the individual value nodes and rename them somehow?

example to a question in the solution read the comments for the full story.

```
    <a>
    <b>
    <Label>zip</Label>
    <Value>6230</Value>
    <Label>city</Label>
    <Value>Rødekro</Value>
    <Label>country</Label>
    <Value>Danmark</Value>
    <c>something</c>
    <Label>date</Label>
    <Value>09/20/2018</Value>
    </b>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ElementTree iterator to travel the nodes.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('temp.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
new_root = ET.Element('address')

it = root.iter()
next(it)
for x in it:
    # skip nodes here or you can add to tree as it is.
    if x.tag != 'Label':
       continue
    child = ET.SubElement(new_root, x.text)
    child.text = next(it).text

print(ET.tostring(new_root))
```

I used this 'temp.xml'

```
<address>
    <Label>zip</Label>
    <Value>6230</Value>
    <Label>city</Label>
    <Value>Rødekro</Value>
    <Label>country</Label>
    <Value>Danmark</Value>
    <c>NOT NEED</c>
    <Label>date</Label>
    <Value>09/20/2018</Value>
</address>
```

Comment: Nice implementation. No XSLT required like I suggested, though that might be a solution for more complex documents.

Comment: @Bouke Thx. It's reliable until the presence and order of the nodes fix.

Comment: That is a beautiful solution, ill need to refine it a little to fit my structure but i love this solution have an upvote :)

Comment: Thx @MrB and Wellcome.

Comment: is it posible to restrict it to a sertain level in the xml file ?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you share an example of your real structure? Btw, you can add 'if' conditions what nodes have to be edited or search for only the root nodes of that.

Comment: say i need to go through a and b to perform your edit without affecting c

see original post for edit

Comment: You can skip nodes inside the loop by conditions. If I understand well, you want to skip 'c' in this situation. I edited the code above. But it can be a problem if 'c' is between 'Label' and 'Value' nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the XML file using XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformation). The [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) library is a well known library suited for this purpose. Because your nodes have no specific names, you have to rely on the node content, such as *zip* and *country* and get the related value from the next node (*Value*).